# how can trace a slowly moving object in html 5 video player

Tags: html, video, html5-video, trace

how can trace a slowly moving object in html 5 video player ie. if ther is an apple falling from the tree then how can I trace that apple falling. If the tracing is with a symbol/image it is more sufficient.

Thanks in advance

Comment: By tracing do you mean tracking, or tracing its outline?

Comment: its tracking... @ken

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that by tracing you mean tracking -

This is something you can't expect to do, at least, real-time in a browser. Even dedicated software such as Mocha or the tracker in After Effects is unable to run real-time tracking of objects most of the time.

Tracking is a complicated mathematical adventure which will iterate exponentially over the pixels to try to (re)locate patterns in the defined area for the trace. This is not impossible to do with JavaScript, but is computational heavy. Considering that Mocha and AE uses compiled c/c++ (as well as hardware acceleration) and is still not fully able to run (always) real-time, it will be close to impossible to do real-time with JavaScript.

You might be able to do it with a ton of compromises but I would rather suggest doing this in one of the aforementioned software and bring over the tracking data (path data) to your JavaScript, bind it to `currentTime` of video and use that to super-impose the object on top of the video. The user will probably be happier with this solution than having the computer fan run immensely from all the processing .-)

If you meant actually tracing the apple then you will run into the same problem as above but at a lesser scale. You could run the frame through line detection and super-impose the result onto the video - however, this would "trace" everything that has a high-frequency presence (ie. lines and details) and there is no way to isolate just the apple without, in advance, knowing its exact position.

Also this is computational heavy and is really not a job for the browser (even if you could do it in JS, just not in real-time). I would suggest, do this kind of work in a dedicated video suite and use the result of that in the browser.

My 2 cents..